# Android - onPostExecute Result doesn't receive info

Tags: java, android, json

I have two codes inside the doInBackground, but only the second passes the data to the `onPostExecute`.
Already tried to debug the code, but it wasn't much helpful. The webservice that I'm using is fully functional, I think.

```
public void onClickWheater(View view){

        new HttpAsyncTask().execute(opa);
    }

    class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
           if(params.equals(opa)){
               try {
               HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://ghelfer.net/weather.aspx?output=json");
               HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
               HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
               int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();


                   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                   String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                   return data;

           } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           } else {

               try {
                   HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://viacep.com.br/ws/" + params[0] + "/json/");
                   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);

                   int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                   if (status == 200) {
                       HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                       String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                       return data;
                   }


               } catch (Exception e) {
                   return null;
               }

           }
            return null;
        }
```

Edit - PostExecute

```
@Override
        public void onPostExecute(String result){
            dialog.dismiss();
            if (result != null){
                try{

                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
                    String logradouro = obj.getString("logradouro");
                    String complemento = obj.getString("complemento");
                    String bairro = obj.getString("bairro");
                    String localidade = obj.getString("localidade");
                    String uf = obj.getString("uf");

                    txtLogradouro.setText(logradouro);
                    txtComplemento.setText(complemento);
                    txtBairro.setText(bairro);
                    txtLocalidade.setText(localidade);
                    txtUF.setText(uf);

                    JSONObject res = new JSONObject(result);

                    JSONArray weather = res.getJSONArray("weather");
                    int dataLength = weather.length();

                    double avgTemp = 0.0;
                    double avgHumid = 0.0;

                    double tempSum = 0.0;
                    double humidSum = 0.0;

                    for (int i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
                        JSONObject tempObj = weather.getJSONObject(i);
                    tempSum += tempObj.getDouble("temperature");
                    humidSum += tempObj.getDouble("humidity");

                }

                if (dataLength != 0) {
                    avgTemp = tempSum/dataLength;
                    avgHumid = humidSum/dataLength;
                }
                String temp = Double.toString(avgTemp);
                txtTemperature.setText(temp);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well where's your `onPostExecute` method?

Comment: @Vucko edited with it.

Comment: Well you do need to debug why your asyncTask is returning `null` to the `onPostExecute`. Turn on debug mode, put breakpoints and follow the result of your HttpClient. That's a good place to start. See if it returns the expected result, and then we can move forward.

Comment: Or at the very least, dump the exception to logcat, `Log.e("...", "bummer", e);`, because `printStackTrace()` does effectively nothing on Android.